# How to adjust text withdash in matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Matplotlib's [`text()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) function applied to axes does not have `linewidth` property.

Following the example, my plot will successfully add the dashes, but they are over 5 whatevers thick while the plot itself uses an elegant `lw=2`.

```
for i in range(len(var)):
    (x2,y2) = DATA[i] 
    ax1.text(x2, y2 , str(y2), fontdict=None, withdash=True,
           dashdirection=1,
           dashlength=10,
           dashpad=5,
           rotation=0,
           dashrotation=90,
           dashpush=10
           )
```

I found this bit of code here at SO to set the line width of all lines in a plot, but it did not successfully target the dash.

```
for ln in ax.lines:
   ln.set_linewidth(20)
```

Any suggestions on how I can target just the dash elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem.

However, I may still know a fix. The dash line properties are relatively easy to change:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a plot with some text with a dash
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = ax.text(.5,.5, "dashtest", withdash=True, dashlength=50)

# change some dash line properties
dash = t.dashline
dash.set_color('r')
dash.set_dashes((5,5))
dash.set_linewidth(5)
```

This gives you:

[image]

The property `t.dashline` is an ordinary `Line2D` instance, so any formatting applicable to a `Line2D` instance can be applied.

Comment: Ty. I think I'll make a second post to ask the followup to this question about how matplotlib encapsulates objects in classes. If I can't figure this out at the site...